# Possible memory leak valgrind c

Tags: c, ubuntu, memory-leaks, pthreads, valgrind

I have just started using valgrind and am not very good with pointers so what I essentially want to do is pass the snake_thread s[1] variable as reference to all the functions so that I don't have to free the memory in each of the functions individually.

```
==20== HEAP SUMMARY:
==20==     in use at exit: 17,704 bytes in 65 blocks
==20==   total heap usage: 75 allocs, 10 frees, 32,646 bytes allocated
==20==
==20== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x10A068: initialize (snake_map_test.c:249)
==20==    by 0x1098C1: main (snake_map_test.c:126)
==20==
==20== 56 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 2 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x10A089: initialize (snake_map_test.c:250)
==20==    by 0x1098C1: main (snake_map_test.c:126)
==20==
==20== 160 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 3 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x10B992: Read_args (snake_map_test.c:571)
==20==    by 0x109887: main (snake_map_test.c:122)
==20==
==20== 272 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 4 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x40149CA: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==20==    by 0x40149CA: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:532)
==20==    by 0x485C322: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:622)
==20==    by 0x485C322: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:660)
==20==    by 0x10972E: main (snake_map_test.c:111)
==20==
==20== 272 bytes in 1 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 5 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x40149CA: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==20==    by 0x40149CA: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:532)
==20==    by 0x485C322: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:622)
==20==    by 0x485C322: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:660)
==20==    by 0x1098F8: main (snake_map_test.c:130)
==20==
==20== 400 bytes in 20 blocks are still reachable in loss record 6 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x10BA1C: Read_args (snake_map_test.c:575)
==20==    by 0x109887: main (snake_map_test.c:122)
==20==
==20== 5,880 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 7 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x10A048: initialize (snake_map_test.c:248)
==20==    by 0x1098C1: main (snake_map_test.c:126)
==20==
==20== 10,608 bytes in 39 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 8 of 8
==20==    at 0x483DD99: calloc (in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==20==    by 0x40149CA: allocate_dtv (dl-tls.c:286)
==20==    by 0x40149CA: _dl_allocate_tls (dl-tls.c:532)
==20==    by 0x485C322: allocate_stack (allocatestack.c:622)
==20==    by 0x485C322: pthread_create@@GLIBC_2.2.5 (pthread_create.c:660)
==20==    by 0x109DD4: run_snake_threads (snake_map_test.c:217)
==20==    by 0x485B608: start_thread (pthread_create.c:477)
==20==    by 0x4997292: clone (clone.S:95)
==20==
==20== LEAK SUMMARY:
==20==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20==      possibly lost: 11,152 bytes in 41 blocks
==20==    still reachable: 6,552 bytes in 24 blocks
==20==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==20==
==20== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==20== For lists of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -s
==20== ERROR SUMMARY: 6 errors from 6 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

These are the relevant functions

```
void* update(void* arg)
{
    snake* s=(snake*)arg;
    
    if (GAMEOVER == false)
    {
        if (s->dir == LEFT)
            s->headX--;
        else if (s->dir == RIGHT)
            s->headX++;
        else if (s->dir == DOWN)
            s->headY++;
        else if (s->dir == UP)
            s->headY--;

    }
   
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

```
void* run_snake_threads(void* arg)
{
    snake_thread* s = (snake_thread*)arg;
    while (GAMEOVER == false)
    {
        pthread_testcancel(); //cancellation point
        map_init(s,s->food);
        if(print_flag==1)
            print(s->map);
        for (int i = 0; i < s->info->size; i++)
        {
            input(s->snake_list, &s->snake_list[i], s->map, s->info,&s->food[i]);
            
            int err = pthread_create(&(s->pid[i]), NULL, update, (void*)&(s->snake_list[i]));
            if (err != 0) ERR("Couldn't create thread");
            
            spawn_food(&s->snake_list[i], s->map,s->food,s->info);
            update_tail(&s->snake_list[i]);
            set_gameover(&s->snake_list[i], s->map);
            usleep(s->snake_list[i].sleep_time);
        }
    }
    free(s->food);
    free(s->pid);
    free(s->snake_list);
    
    pthread_exit(0);
}
```

```
void initialize(snake_thread* s,int argc,char** argv)
{
    s->snake_list = calloc(s->info->size,sizeof(snake) );
    s->pid = calloc(s->info->size, sizeof(pthread_t) );
    s->food=calloc(s->info->size,sizeof(snake_food));
    //does some stuff and passes s to other functions   
}
```

```
void Read_args(int argc, char** argv,snake_thread* s)
{
    int c;
    if (argc > 1)
        while ((c = getopt(argc, argv, "x:y:f:")) != -1)
            switch (c)
            {
            case 'x':
                s->info->width_provided = true;
                s->map->width = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'y':
                s->info->height_provided = true;
                s->map->height = atoi(optarg);
                break;
            case 'f':
                s->info->file_name_provided = true;
                strcpy(s->info->file,optarg);
                break;
            default:
                usage(argv[0]);
                break;
            }
    else usage(argv[0]);
    if(!(s->info->file))
    {
        strcpy(s->info->file,getenv("$SNAKEFILE"));
        if(!(s->info->file))
        {
            printf("Warning, No save file provided\n");
        }
    }
    init_size(argc,s->info);
   
    //if(argc>optind) ERR("optind err");
    s->map->map_elem_pos = calloc(s->map->height,sizeof(char*));
    if (s->map->map_elem_pos == NULL) ERR("Malloc error for elements of map");

    for (int i = 0; i < s->map->height; i++)
        s->map->map_elem_pos[i] = calloc(s->map->width,sizeof(char));
}
```

```
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    pthread_t pid;
    snake_thread s[1]
    Read_args(argc, argv, s);
    if (access(s->info->file, F_OK) != 0)
        initialize(s,argc,argv);
    int err = pthread_create(&s->pid2, NULL, run_snake_threads, (void*)s);
    if (err) ERR("Couldn't create thread");
    pthread_join(s->pid2, NULL);
}
```

Comment: You never free any of the memory you allocate in `read_args`.

Comment: Why do you create an array with one element? Just declare `snake_thread s;` and then use `&s` in the arguments.

Comment: Does the 'do some stuff' in `Read_args()` initialize `s->map` so that the references in the code shown are valid?  Where do you call `free()`?  You've not shown much code that frees memory.  You wait for one thread to finish but you create many threads — that isn't a recipe for happiness either.  And the free operations you show occur after creating many threads and apparently passing pointers to the data that is subsequently freed to those threads — and you free the data before you know that the threads are finished with it.  Are those possible leaks the only reported issues?

Comment: @JonathanLeffler The s->map is initialized in the run_snake_threads function pointer. So I am not very good with pointers so what I essentially want to do is pass the snake_thread s variable declared in main by reference to all the functions so that I don't have to free them individually

Comment: @Barmar Yeah you're right I should have done that however the outcome is stil the same

Comment: Well, they aren't going to free themselves, so you're going to have to write code to free every scrap of memory that you allocate dynamically.  It is hard for us to help you since we don't have an MCVE ([Minimal, Complete, Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
 — or MRE or whatever name SO now uses)
or an
SSCCE ([Short, Self-Contained, Correct Example](http://sscce.org/)) to analyze.  So all we can do is make general comments and plausible guesses. Creating an MCVE is important. So is reading the reports from Valgrind which gives you line numbers for unfreed allocations.

Comment: Every time you call a dynamic memory allocation function (`malloc()` et al), you should know where you are going to free that dynamically allocated memory.  You should also check that the allocation was successful and take appropriate action if it fails.